# Evaluating the SDE $dX_t = t\,dS_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, sde, differential-equations, stochastic

The process $S$ is a geometric Brownian motion with an SDE: $dS_t = S_t(\sigma\, dB_t + \mu\, dt)$. I'm stuck evaluating $E(X_t)$ and $V(X_t)$, where $dX_t = t\,dS_t$.

Answer (score 4):

Using Itô's Lemma, notice that:
$$d(tS_t)=tdS_t+S_tdt=dX_t+S_tdt$$
Hence:
$$X_t=tS_t-\int S_udu$$
Using independence of Brownian increments, $E(S_udW_u)=E(S_u)E(dW_u)=0$, and the chain rule for the 4th step:
$$\begin{align}
E(X_t)&=E\left(\int dX_u\right)
\\
&=\int uE(dS_u)
\\
&=\int u\mu E(S_u)du
\\
&=S_0\int u\mu e^{\mu u}du
\\
&=S_0\left(te^{\mu t}-\int e^{\mu u}du\right)
\\
&=S_0\left(te^{\mu t}-\frac{1}{\mu}(e^{\mu t}-1)\right)
\end{align}
$$

**[Note: my previous variance calculation was wrong, will fix it when available.]**

Comment: Thanks. Quite to the point. Solving the equation for Xt, can I use ito lemma with f(x,t)=d((log s)/t)?

Comment: @CharlesSmith I have updated my answer.

Comment: I am not sure whether $f(S_t,t)=\log (S_t)/t$ is the best option.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw I am pretty sure the plus signs in the last two expressions in the calculation of the expectation should be minus signs.

Also, (you seem much more experienced so I may be totally off base here) I think that there may be an issue in calculating the Variance's first term since in the Variance the $\mathbb E [(\int u \mu S_u du)^2]$ term should appear as a double integral using two different dummy variables. So the $dt^2$ argument doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Slade correct on both counts, I did this too hastily. For variance, I was using independence of $S_u$ and $dW_u$ to separate the total variance into the sum of the "drift part" and the "diffusion part", but I messed it up as $S_u$ multiplies $dW_u$ so the two integrals are not independent.

Comment: Yeah the variance calculation looks very cumbersome. I couldn't simplify it much so I'll leave it to you to see if you can get it to a manageable form